# How to write Spark-submit logs file with the Scala code?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, logging, log4j, spark-submit

I am trying to build a scala based jar file that uses log4j to write logs. Executing the code above with spark-shell works fine (logs printing in the console). But when I try to make it write to a log file (spark-shell or spark-submit), only the line with logging.info is print out. I wish to set the log level to DEBUG. Here is my code :

```
import org.apache.log4j
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger, PatternLayout, Priority, RollingFileAppender}

import java.time
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

trait SparkContextProvider {
  def spark: SparkSession
}

trait Logs extends SparkContextProvider {

  lazy val logging: log4j.Logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass.getName)
  lazy val applicationId: String = spark.sparkContext.applicationId

  val appender = new RollingFileAppender()
    appender.setAppend(true)
    appender.setMaxFileSize("50MB")
    appender.setMaxBackupIndex(10)
    appender.setFile("/usr/spark-3.0.2/app-logs/spark-" + applicationId + ".log")
    appender.activateOptions()

  val layOut = new PatternLayout()
    layOut.setConversionPattern("%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n")

  appender.setLayout(layOut)
  logging.addAppender(appender)
  logging.setLevel(Level.DEBUG)
}



object DataExtractionProcess extends Logs {
    def Main(): Unit = {
        logging.info("hello test world")
    }
    
    override def spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder
        .appName("PredictiveDataOperation")
        .getOrCreate()
        
}
```

I trigger the job with DataExtractionProcess.Main()
And I tried also to set log level with :

```
//Logger.getLogger("org.apache.spark").setLevel(Level.DEBUG)
//Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.DEBUG)
//spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("all")
```

But no change in the log file.

Thanks for the help

Comment: What log output are you expecting that you're not seeing?

Comment: I want to write all logs (debug level) from a job executed with spark-submit. Typically, all logs that i see in the console when a job is running with spark-submit command. Thanks a lot